# Arquillian: combining local and container code

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I'm working with Arquillian with the JBoss 7 managed container.  I'm writing a test to do the following:

- Prepare the test locally, not on the JBoss server.
- Run the test on the JBoss server.
- Validate the output, not on the JBoss server.

Here is my first attempt at this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class NotWorking {
    @Inject
    private Service service;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testService() throws Exception {
        prepare();
        service.executeService();
        validate();
    }

    @RunAsClient
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        LocalOnlyClass.prepare();
    }

    @RunAsClient
    public void validate() throws Exception {
        LocalOnlyClass.validate();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  Arquillian tries to run the preparation and validation on the server and fails to find the LocalOnlyClass.  I can get this to work as follows but its ugly:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class Working {
    @Inject
    private Service service;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void testService1Prepare() throws Exception {
        LocalOnlyClass.prepare();
    }

    @Test
    public void testService2Test() throws Exception {
        service.executeService();
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void testService3Validate() throws Exception {
        LocalOnlyClass.validate();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this that avoids the "fake" tests?

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about your comment:

> Unfortunately this doesn't work. Arquillian tries to run the
>   preparation and validation on the server and fails to find the
>   LocalOnlyClass.

If your problem really lies in where the code gets executed, I don't see how JUnits `@FixMethodOrder` would make a difference. It just forces a execution order of the tests. The same can be achieved with Arquillian's `@InSequence` annotation which is what I would recommend in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  You're quite right in saying that the `@FixMethodOrder` doesn't in itself fix the problem.  What fixes it is putting the `@RunAsClient`around a `@Test` method rather than a non-test method.  The `@FixMethodOrder` along with the naming of the tests are then used just to make sure that everything runs in the right order.